# how to put another json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, laravel-blade

I am building **laravel** blade php file.
I need to make **json data** for calendar schedule.
But I can't put each data to json.
This result come as all same records.

**The code is like below...**

```
@foreach($room_rates as $key=>$room_rate)
  var roomRate_object = {
    id: "{{$room_rate->sup_hotel_room_rates_list_id}}",
    roomRate_name: "{{$room_rate->room->room_name}}",
    roomRate_nameCode: "{{$room_rate->sup_room_details_id}}",
    roomRate_type: "2",
    roomRate_value: "3",
    start: "{{$room_rate->from_date}}",
    end: "{{$room_rate->to_date}}",
    status: "{{$room_rate->status}}",
    allotmant: "{{1}}",
    night_stayval: "{{$room_rate->min_night_stay}}",
  };
  console.log("kkk roomRate_object")
  console.log(roomRate_object)
  
  roomRate_object.id = roomRate_object.id + "1";
  roomRate_object.roomRate_type = "1";
  roomRate_object.roomRate_value = "{{$room_rate->adult_rate}}";
  realize_schedule.push(roomRate_object);

  roomRate_object.id = roomRate_object.id + "2";
  roomRate_object.roomRate_type = "2";
  roomRate_object.roomRate_value = "{{$room_rate->double_rate}}";
  realize_schedule.push(roomRate_object);

  roomRate_object.id = roomRate_object.id + "3";
  roomRate_object.roomRate_type = "3";
  roomRate_object.roomRate_value = "{{$room_rate->triple_rate}}";
  realize_schedule.push(roomRate_object);

  roomRate_object.id = roomRate_object.id + "4";
  roomRate_object.roomRate_type = "4";
  roomRate_object.roomRate_value = "{{$room_rate->quad_rate}}";
  realize_schedule.push(roomRate_object);

  roomRate_object.id = roomRate_object.id + "5";
  roomRate_object.roomRate_type = "5";
  roomRate_object.roomRate_value = "{{$room_rate->child_rate}}";
  realize_schedule.push(roomRate_object);
@endforeach
```

**The result is like this.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddAYv.png)

That are very strange.
Please help me.

I am very worried about that.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please fix your code example, it misses foreach start.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I will fix.

Comment: you're repeatedly pushing the same object to the array. _All_ the reference to that object in your array will change whenever you change the original object. Instead, declare a different object each time. Even better, you could just get PHP to generate this data up-front without all this repetitive stuff.

Comment: https://nhn.github.io/tui.calendar/latest/
You can reference from it.
And source is https://github.com/nhn/tui.calendar

Comment: I can use it on Laravel?

Comment: Sure. Please see it first.
And You can it on Laravel.

Comment: Thanks. It is used in blade for inserting js file each page?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are a little confuse with the reference changing. In javascript when a object is created and if you try to modify the value of the object then it will change the value in the memory. Example

```
var obj = {name:'test'};
var b = obj;
b.name = 'test2';
```

if you console the output then both obj and b will have test2 because javascript will change  the value in the memory as on line var b = obj it is just making b to point to the same memory which is used by obj.

For escaping this technique we use deep cloning or shallow cloning as per the needs.

You have many options one can be you just create multiple objects with diferent name.

For making new object

```
function getObj($room_rate,id,type,value){
  return {
   id: "{{$room_rate->sup_hotel_room_rates_list_id}}"+ id,
   roomRate_name: "{{$room_rate->room->room_name}}",
   roomRate_nameCode: "{{$room_rate->sup_room_details_id}}",
   roomRate_type: type,
   roomRate_value: value,
   start: "{{$room_rate->from_date}}",
   end: "{{$room_rate->to_date}}",
   status: "{{$room_rate->status}}",
   allotmant: "{{1}}",
   night_stayval: "{{$room_rate->min_night_stay}}",
 }
}
```

Create function like above

and call it like

```
realize_schedule.push(getObj($room_rate,"1","{{$room_rate->adult_rate}}"));
```

This above snippet is just an example and just for the idea how you can tackle your problem

Comment: So I have to make each json objects?

Comment: Edited the answer for the reference

Comment: $room_rate is variable in foreach.
So it can use in this function?

Comment: Yes, as per the languages you can pass anything to functions whether it is inside a function or not.
All it depends on the right syntax.
I have given you the answer on the basis of javascript but maybe for passing the variable to function needs a different syntax for PHP but im not sure ,

Answer (score 0):

You have to use each object for this.

```
var roomRate_object = {
    id: "{{$room_rate->sup_hotel_room_rates_list_id.'1'}}",
    roomRate_name: "{{$room_rate->room->room_name}}",
    roomRate_nameCode: "{{$room_rate->sup_room_details_id}}",
    roomRate_type: "1",
    roomRate_value: "{{$room_rate->adult_rate}}",
    start: "{{$room_rate->from_date}}",
    end: "{{$room_rate->to_date}}",
    status: "{{$room_rate->status}}",
    allotmant: "{{1}}",
    night_stayval: "{{$room_rate->min_night_stay}}",
  };
realize_schedule.push(roomRate_object);

var roomRate_object = {
    id: "{{$room_rate->sup_hotel_room_rates_list_id.'2'}}",
    roomRate_name: "{{$room_rate->room->room_name}}",
    roomRate_nameCode: "{{$room_rate->sup_room_details_id}}",
    roomRate_type: "2",
    roomRate_value: "{{$room_rate->double_rate}}",
    start: "{{$room_rate->from_date}}",
    end: "{{$room_rate->to_date}}",
    status: "{{$room_rate->status}}",
    allotmant: "{{1}}",
    night_stayval: "{{$room_rate->min_night_stay}}",
  };
realize_schedule.push(roomRate_object);

var roomRate_object = {
    id: "{{$room_rate->sup_hotel_room_rates_list_id.'3'}}",
    roomRate_name: "{{$room_rate->room->room_name}}",
    roomRate_nameCode: "{{$room_rate->sup_room_details_id}}",
    roomRate_type: "3",
    roomRate_value: "{{$room_rate->triple_rate}}",
    start: "{{$room_rate->from_date}}",
    end: "{{$room_rate->to_date}}",
    status: "{{$room_rate->status}}",
    allotmant: "{{1}}",
    night_stayval: "{{$room_rate->min_night_stay}}",
  };
realize_schedule.push(roomRate_object);
```

Comment: So are there are no good method for that?

Comment: Anyways, yes. you should use another object for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use another object for put another data to json.
So do make like below codes.
I made this for you.

```
@foreach($room_rates as $key=>$room_rate)
  @for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
    var roomRate_object = {
    id: "{{$room_rate->sup_hotel_room_rates_list_id}}",
    roomRate_name: "{{$room_rate->room->room_name}}",
    roomRate_nameCode: "{{$room_rate->sup_room_details_id}}",
    roomRate_type: "{{$i}}",
    roomRate_value: "3",
    start: "{{$room_rate->from_date}}",
    end: "{{$room_rate->to_date}}",
    status: "{{$room_rate->status}}",
    allotmant: "{{1}}",
    night_stayval: "{{$room_rate->min_night_stay}}",
  };

  @switch($i)
    @case(1)
        roomRate_object.roomRate_value = "{{$room_rate->adult_rate}}";
        @break

    @case(2)
        roomRate_object.roomRate_value = "{{$room_rate->double_rate}}";
        @break

    @case(3)
        roomRate_object.roomRate_value = "{{$room_rate->triple_rate}}";
        @break

    @case(4)
        roomRate_object.roomRate_value = "{{$room_rate->quad_rate}}";
        @break

    @case(5)
        roomRate_object.roomRate_value = "{{$room_rate->child_rate}}";
        @break

    @default
        <span>Something went wrong, please try again</span>
  @endswitch

  realize_schedule.push(roomRate_object);
  @endfor
  console.log("kkk roomRate_object")
  console.log(roomRate_object)
  
@endforeach
```

I used another object to input json data.

If the result is wrong, let me know.
I will spend my gold time for you.
Good lucky.

Comment: Thanks. that is good, I think.
And this is working well.

Comment: Hello. Could I use one object instead of that?
I mean without redefine variable as roomRate_object

Comment: No, you should redefine that. Because it is used address of object.

Comment: Thanks. I will need your help forwards.

Comment: Do you have experiences in Calendar Schedule js?

Comment: Yes. You can use it for that.

Comment: This is tui-calendar.js

Comment: If you have example for that, please send it.